# ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

I need to perform a multiplication in order to get a regressed value from my features i, x, y, z, n, like so:

```
# use only one sample
feats = np.array([i, x, y, z, n]).reshape(1, -1)

# scale
scaler = StandardScaler()

# fit
feat_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(feats)

# multiply and get regressed value --> 'reg' is regression object
val = feat_scaled @ reg.coef_ + reg.intercept_
```

Where:

```
print (reg.coef_.shape, feat_scaled.shape)

(55,) (1, 5)
```

But i'm getting the error:

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 55 is different from 5)
```

---

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`reg.coef_` shape is `(5,)` and therefore the dot product with `feat_scaled` cannot be perform. this array need to be reshape to `(5, 1)`.

As follows:

```
feat_scaled @ reg.coef_.reshape(-1,1)+ reg.intercept_
```